Can I replace the seals on Ikea fridge / freezer?
Does anyone know if I can replace the seals on the Ikea fridge freezer model 101.824.86?
My current seals are mouldy and it seems a bit overkill to need to replace the entire fridge / freezer due to this. The seals are damaged - they have split all the way along the length of them where the mould has grown.
I've tries following steps from different YouTube videos but when I go to pull the seal off it seems properly glued and I don't want to wrench it off if it means I can't get anything back on.


Washing the seals with bleach will probably be much easier than replacing.  You replace seals if they are damaged.

I should have been more specific, the seals are damaged, they have slits along the length where they have split open and the mould has grown.

A search for door seals will provide quite a few options for replacements.  Using the make and model number will be more specific for your fridge.

Ah, you are (probably) in Europe.  Have you contacted Ikea EU to see if they carry parts?

Research who makes fridges for Ikea to find the parts.

I've contacted IKEA and they told me it's a discontinued product so cannot help with replacement parts. They gave me a link to a different site that has parts - but I'm not even sure that the seals are replaceable and researching online gives me nothing.

A picture of the seals with the splits would possibly help. "the seals ... have slits along the length where they have split open" 'Along the length' sounds to me like these slits could have been there all along. I have a vague remembering of having seen some kind of door seals with full-length intentional "slits" before. Maybe they're just supposed to be cleaned.

If it's down to the point of "replace the fridge" .vs. improvise seals, using generic weatherstripping as intended for a house door may be worth considering. At nearly 26 years old (the sticker appears to say it was made in 1999) a new fridge might be enough more efficient to justify the replacement, but if bad door seals are the only problem, it might not.
If the parts supplier Ikea sent you to has parts, there should be some indication of how the part is installed. If glued in place, heat often helps to remove glue.

New fridges might beat an older one on efficiently, but quite a few stories(plus a couple of lawsuits) about new fridges breaking down much sooner.  Seems efficiently has gone up but quality has gone down on some of the big names.

"Generic weather stripping" likely would not work -- almost all fridges use rubber magnetic strips on the seal for door closure. However, one might find magnetic rubber stripping.
